# How to best apply compression in Windows to speed up a slow disk with a powerful CPU?

Tags: windows, cpu, performance, ntfs, compression

I have a desktop PC with a reasonably powerful Ryzen 3700X (8c/16t) that runs Linux. I need to occasionally use Windows, but not often enough to justify dual-booting. I have instead installed Windows 11 as Windows-to-go on a 512GB MicroSD card and it's working just great, except at 160Mbps read speed, file load times can be sluggish.

Now, because the CPU is fast and the disk is slow, I'm assuming that compressing the data on the disk would significantly improve the load times as the CPU would be able to keep up with even fairly sophisticated decompression algorithms.

The question is, how should I compress the disk? Is checking the "Compress this drive" option in properties my best bet? I've heard of CompactOS and applied it, but it compresses only the OS itself. Should CompactOS be used in conjunction with other methods or would that result in double-compression? Apparently it's possible to use the `compact` command to apply the more modern LZX algorithm to arbitrary folders, but that gets undone on writes. Is it worth using and is there a way to automate it? Are there worthwhile 3rd party tools?

Comment: The read speed of SD cards is usually not the problem but the random access time (-> IOPS) and often the used SD card reader.

Comment: There are USB  SSD drives for US$50 and up that might have better I/O speed. As @Robert states, the random access speed may be the limiting factor on the flash-memory card. Of course, you could run Windows in VM, instead.

Comment: “Now, because the CPU is fast and the disk is slow, I'm assuming that compressing the data on the disk would significantly improve the load times as the CPU would be able to keep up with even fairly sophisticated decompression algorithms.” - It actually won’t. Compression would help slightly if you were running out of space. There is a reason Windows 2 Go support was discontinued 4+ years ago. You would be better off with a second physical disk connected to a faster interface. The feature was discontinued even after USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 was released.